# Simple video player for Android "Can't play this video"

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

So, I'm trying to make a very simple video player for Android and running it on my `Samsung Galaxy S3`, but it keeps giving me the message "We're sorry, this video file cannot be played". The thing is I tried different videos,including videos that were recorded with the very same phone, and the problem can't be the video. The code is so simple, I just ran out of ideas on where the problem might be and so I'm asking for help. It's probably something stupid.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            String videoToPlay = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera/20140524_183346.mp4";
            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoToPlay);
            videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            videoView.start();  
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

If you need anything else, let me know and thanks for your help.

Edit for error addition: 
10-20 12:51:56.735: E/MediaPlayer(20398): Error (1,-2147483648)
10-20 12:51:56.735: D/VideoView(20398): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: Please check your device path for video

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns the sd card root, right? From there I'msure about the path. Also have tried to play from the phone itself, same results.

Comment: make sure you have specified permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` inside your manifest file.

Comment: Have done this. Also went to check if the file exists with the exists() method and it is returning false, although the directory is right and the file is definitely there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: User `Log.d("filepath",videoToPlay);` to checkout the path which you are having right now.

Comment: Found the problem, although i don't get it: even though i'm using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), the actual path is leading me to the phone memory, so if i put the video inside the phone memory but use the exact same path written in the code above it works. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: android treats it as external storage.

Comment: can you tell me how to get to the actual external storage then?